# Refs do not update immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

```
const selectedBillID = useRef("");
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([
  {
    "Bill ID": 1,
    TotalBill: "$7.43",
    "NoOf Products": 1,
    Date: "7/15/2022",
    "Payment Status": "Completed",
  },
  {
    "Bill ID": 2,
    TotalBill: "$2.15",
    "NoOf Products": 2,
    Date: "3/28/2022",
    "Payment Status": "Completed",
  },
  {
    "Bill ID": 3,
    TotalBill: "$0.07",
    "NoOf Products": 3,
    Date: "4/6/2022",
    "Payment Status": "Completed",
  }]);

const handleClickTableRow = billID => (selectedBillID.current = billID)

<CustomTable mt={2} columns={tableColumns}>
        {tableData.map((row, index) => (
          <TableRow
            key={index}
            hover
            onClick={() => handleClickTableRow(row["Bill ID"])}
          >
            {Object.entries(row).map(([_label, value], index) => (
              <TableCell key={index} style={{ cursor: "default" }}>
                {value}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </CustomTable>
```

Problem
when I click on table row it doesn't update the ref immediately it only updates after a state update when i type something on a text field the ref updates I cannot figure out what the problem is , i need help guys thanks in advance

Comment: how do you know it doesn't update the ref?

Comment: i used react dev tools to monitor

Comment: Don't rely on React Dev Tools, try putting a console.log in useEffect with selectedBillID as the dependency.

Comment: @NishithSavla `ref` shouldn't go as dependency, OP can just console.log after assignment to check it

Comment: I tried with useEffect but Still getting the same result it doesn't update immediately Idk y